# How do I change this query so that it only returns data based on a yes or no entry in a table column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, lookup-tables

This is the core of the query
    USE FloridaHousingDB

```
SELECT   [Codes].[Description],  COUNT(*) As 'Number Units' 
FROM     HousingInfo, Codes, Categories 
WHERE    HousingInfo.ACR = Codes.Name
AND    Codes.CategoryName = 'ACR'
AND    Categories.Name = Codes.CategoryName
GROUP BY [Codes].[Description]
```

currently it returns as this

```
House on less than one acre 170745

House on one to less than ten acres 20940

House on ten acres or more  2586
```

What I need to do is figure out how to have select in that same format except that it would only return the number of units that also had an FS value of Yes with the YES being under the description column

```
Name CategoryName Description
1   REGION         Northeast
2   REGION         Midwest
3   REGION         South
4   REGION         West
9   REGION         Puerto Rico
1   TYPE           Housing Unit
2   TYPE           Institutional Group Quarters
1   TYPE           Noninstitutional Group Quarters
b   ACR            N/A
1   ACR            House on less than one acre
2   ACR            House on one to less than ten acres
3   ACR            House on ten acres or more
b   FS             N/A
1   FS             Yes
2   FS             No
NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: "select in that same format except that it would only return the number of units that also had and FS value of Yes" This is a very confusing sentence. You've explicitly excluded FS units - and there is no relationship in any of your sample data from ACR to FS.  I'm guessing you just want `WHERE Codes.CategoryName IN ('FS', 'ACR')`, but it's hard to tell the way you've worded your question.

Comment: sorry dealing with a bit of a headache at the moment, specifically in the bottom of the third section the last 2 rows it has

1   FS             Yes

2   FS             No

I need to figure out how to add to the core code so that it would only return Houses that also were in the Yes under description, in the main database table FS values are B,1,2 
in the 3rd section
b=N/A
1 = Yes
2 = No
I need to return only house that would fall in the Yes category

Comment: Again, complete sentences help.  If you want people to help you, you gotta put in a little more effort to clarify your request.

Comment: I would suggest you start using ANSI-92 style joins...they have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: not quite used to the enter key having it submit instead of dropping to the next line

Answer (score 0):

If I've sufficiently deciphered your question, I think you just need to modify your `WHERE` clause to also include 'FS' codes with description of 'YES':

```
SELECT   [Codes].[Description],  COUNT(*) As 'Number Units' 
FROM     HousingInfo, Codes, Categories 
WHERE    HousingInfo.ACR = Codes.Name
AND    Categories.Name = Codes.CategoryName
AND    (
            Codes.CategoryName = 'ACR'
            OR
                (
                    Codes.CategoryName = 'FS'
                    AND 
                    Codes.Description = 'YES'
                )
        )
GROUP BY [Codes].[Description]
```

Comment: And, for the love of God - please read up on `JOIN` syntax - you're using ancient syntax that is universally frowned upon.  I left it the way it is because your question seems to center around the `WHERE` clause, but you really should fix the whole query.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Stan.  Here's the more modern join syntax:

SELECT   [Codes].[Description],  COUNT(*) As 'Number Units' 
FROM     HousingInfo
         inner join Codes on HousingInfo.ACT = Codes.Name
         inner join Categories on Categories.Name = Codes.CategoryName
WHERE    (
            Codes.CategoryName = 'ACR'
            OR
                (
                    Codes.CategoryName = 'FS'
                    AND 
                    Codes.Description = 'YES'
                )
        )
GROUP BY [Codes].[Description]

Comment: Sorry the line feeds didn't take